# Javascript - Jquery Move Div Keydown Barrier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to create a moveable div on keydown. I have managed to work the keydown function using Jquery. However, I would like to create barriers which the div cannot move over and must go around.

A bit like a mini map for the div.

I have been testing my code using JSfiddle and would appreciate any help I receive:

http://jsfiddle.net/bDMnX/828/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pane">
    <div id="barrier"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pane {
    position:relative;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#box {
    position:absolute; top:140px; left:140px;
    width:20px; height:20px;          
    background-color:black;
}
#barrier{
    position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;
    width:50px; height:50px;          
    background-color:grey; 
}
```

**JS:**

```
var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    w = pane.width() - box.width(),
    d = {},
    x = 3;

function newv(v,a,b) {
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n;
}

$(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); },
        top: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
    });
}, 20);
```

I might not be using the best method for this and would be open to feedback on ways to improve or better this code.

I would like to be able to stop the #box div from touching/going over #barrier.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code which will allow you to drag the small div using mouse and also using arrow keys.
Have made small changes in HTML and CSS also.

You need to include this script also in head portion:

#### Dependencies:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="pane">
     <div id="barrier"><div id="box"></div></div>    
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
 #pane {
        position:relative;
        width:300px; height:300px;
        border:2px solid red;
 }    
 #box {
       width:20px; height:20px;          
       background-color:black;
 }
 #barrier{
      position:relative; top:50px; left:50px;
      width:50px; height:50px;          
      background-color:grey; 
 }
```

#### JS:

```
    $(function(){
            var pane = $('#pane'),
            box = $('#box'),
            barrier = $('#barrier'),
            distance = 1,
            position;
            $( "#box" ).draggable({ 
                containment: "#barrier", 
                scroll: false
            });
            $(window).on('keypress', function(e){
                position = box.position();
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 37: position.left -= distance; break; // Left
                    case 38: position.top  -= distance; break; // Up
                    case 39: position.left += distance; break; // Right
                    case 40: position.top  += distance; break; // Down
                    default: return true; // Exit and bubble
                }
                // Keep draggable within container
                if (position.left >= 0 && position.top >= 0 &&
                    position.left + box.width() <= barrier.width() &&
                    position.top + box.height() <= barrier.height()) {
                    box.css(position);
                }
            });
        });
```

Note: While testing using arrow keys make sure you click the page and play with arrows.